# Downloading a file with dynamic filename on Sharepoint URL

Tags: string, sharepoint, formatting, wildcard

Good afternoon everyone!

I'm trying to download a file from Sharepoint. The thing is the URL of the file is dynamic on **date.**

Example:

```
Filename 12.04.2021.xlsx #the date change dynamically
```

Here the code

```
sp = da_tran_SP365(site_url = xxxxxx
               , client_id = xxxxx
               , client_secret = xxxxx)

# Create download path from download URL
download_path = sp.create_link('https://mysite.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/myfolder/Filename_12.04.2021.xlsx)
```

Do I need to put a wildcard or something? I need to tell python to expect a number or string dd.mm.yyyy on that part of the code.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use a link to the document on SharePoint without the `/:x:/r` in the URL, otherwise SharePoint will expect more parameters for the link. Try the following convention instead, which is a direct link to the file.

'https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/myfolder/Filename_12.04.2021.xlsx'